# "Must read" papers in numerical analysis

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, big-list

In 1993, [Prof. L.N. Trefethen](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/) published a [NA-net](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/classic_papers.txt) posting with a list of thirteen paper he used for teaching the seminar **Classic Papers in Numerical Analysis**. 
In Trefethen's words, *... this course provided a satisfying vison of the broad scope of numerical analysis and the sense of excitement at what a diversity of beautiful and powerful ideas have been invented in this field.*

Prof. Trefethen's list ([links](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/classics/)):

1. Cooley & Tukey (1965)              [the Fast Fourier Transform](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/cooley-tukey.pdf)
2. Courant, Friedrichs & Lewy (1928)  [finite difference methods for PDE](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/courant-friedrichs-lewy.pdf)
3. Householder (1958)                 [QR factorization of matrices](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/householder.pdf)
4. Curtiss & Hirschfelder (1952)      [stiffness of ODEs; BD formulas](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/curtiss-hirschfelder.pdf)
5. de Boor (1972)                     [calculations with B-splines](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/deboor.pdf)
6. Courant (1943)                     [finite element methods for PDE](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/courant.pdf)
7. Golub & Kahan (1965)               [the singular value decomposition](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/golub-kahan.pdf)
8. Brandt (1977)                      [multigrid algorithms](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/brandt.pdf)
9. Hestenes & Stiefel (1952)          [the conjugate gradient iteration](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/hestenes-stiefel.pdf)
10. Fletcher & Powell (1963)          [optimization via quasi-Newton updates](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/classics/fletcher-powell.pdf)
11. Wanner, Hairer & Norsett (1978)   [order stars and applications to ODE](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/wanner-hairer-norsett.pdf)
12. Karmarkar (1984)                  [interior pt. methods for linear prog.](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/classics/karmarkar.pdf)
13. Greengard & Rokhlin (1987)        [multipole methods for particles](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/classics/greengard-rokhlin.pdf)

*Most readers of this note*, according Prof. Trefethen, *will have thought of other classic authors and papers that should have been on the list.*

> > The question is: In your opinion, what are other classic authors and papers that should be in a **must read** list of papers in numerical analysis?

Comment: See a Who is Who of numerical analysis in Trefethen's [Who invented the great numerical algorithms?](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/inventorstalk.pdf).

Comment: Dear PaPiro: Please read the guidelines at http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask and rewrite your question.

Answer (score 13):

Metropolis N, Ulam S (1949) The Monte Carlo method *J. Am. Stat. Assoc.* **44**:335-341

Marsaglia G (1968) Random numbers fall mainly in the planes. *Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA* **61**:25-28

Answer (score 12):

J. von Neumann, H.H. Goldstine, *Numerical Inverting of Matrices of High Order*, [Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-53/issue-11/Numerical-inverting-of-matrices-of-high-order/bams/1183511222.full), Vol. 53, No. 11, pp. 1021-1099, 1947.

According to J. Grcar, *Birthday of Modern Numerical Analysis*, available [here](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/users/vuik/wi211/num_anal.html) or [here](https://www.netlib.org/na-digest-html/97/v97n46.html#5), this paper is considered the **first** paper in *modern* analysis because *it is the first to study rounding error and because much of the paper is an essay on scientific computing (albeit with an emphasis on numerical linear algebra).*

Answer (score 9):

Fermi, Pasta, Ulam, *Studies of Nonlinear Problems*, unpublished report from Los Alamos National Laboratory, 1955.

This paper arguably started the numerical investigation of nonlinear dynamics and chaos, which has become a huge field.  See for example Ford, *The Fermi-Pasta-Ulam problem: Paradox turns discovery*, Physics Reports 213 (2002) pp. 271-310 for a review.

Comment: The Fermi, Pasta and Ulam report is available at http://www.osti.gov/accomplishments/documents/fullText/ACC0041.pdf


Answer (score 7):

P. D. Lax & B. Wendroff. *On the stability of difference schemes*, Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics **15**, pp 363–371 (1962).

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160150401/abstract a comment why it is "must read " -  I think would be worth for many. From abstract I see that "they covered many previously known results", but for outsider this is not informative.

Answer (score 6):

[J. Crank and P. Nicolson (1947) A practical method for numerical evaluation of solutions of partial differential equations of the heat-conduction type. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society 43, pp. 50-67](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2035556&fulltextType=RA&fileId=S0305004100023197)

Answer (score 5):

S.K. Godunov, *A difference method for numerical calculation of discontinuous solutions of the equations of hydrodynamics*, Matematicheskii Sbornik (1959).  (in Russian)

Virtually all modern methods for nonlinear hyperbolic PDEs are based on this.

Comment: Gordunov's paper (in Russian) is available at http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=4873&option_lang=eng


Answer (score 4):

Jinchao Xu, *Iterative methods by space decomposition and subspace correction*, SIAM Review 34(4):581-613, 1992.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a classic paper, but I would add Xiu, D. and Karniadakis, G.E, "The Wiener-Askey Polynomial Chaos for Stochastic Differential Equations," which can be found [here](http://www.dam.brown.edu/scicomp/media/report_files/BrownSC-2003-07.pdf).

I mention this paper because Generalized Polynomial Chaos is still underrepresented in many fields, though it has found much use in engineering applications. It is not precisely a magic bullet, but in some cases it can drastically reduce computational demand in uncertainty analysis. The aforementioned paper is a good summary of the method.

Answer (score 2):

Edward N. Lorenz (1963). "Deterministic Nonperiodic Flow". Journal of the Atmospheric Sciences 20 (2): 130–141.

This demonstrated the butterfly effect.

Comment: This is not a numerical analysis paper.

Answer (score 2):

L.F. Richardson, *The Approximate Arithmetical Solution by Finite Differences of Physical Problems Involving Differential Equations, with an Application to the Stresses in a Masonry Dam*, Proceedings of the Royal Society of London, 1910, available [here](http://archive.org/stream/philtrans04693161/04693161#page/n0/mode/2up).

From the Abstract,

> The object of this paper is to develop methods whereby 
>   the differential equations of physics may be applied more freely than hitherto in the 
>   approximate form of difference equations to problems concerning irregular bodies. (... ...).
>
> Both for engineering and for many of the less exact sciences, such as biology, there 
>   is a demand for rapid methods, easy to be understood and applicable to unusual 
>   equations and irregular bodies. If they can be accurate, so much the better ; but 
>   1 per cent, would suffice for many purposes. It is hoped that the methods put 
>   forward in this paper will help to supply this demand.

According [CFD-Online](http://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/History_of_CFD), this 50 page paper is a key paper in Computational Fluid Dynamics.

Answer (score 2):

Any mention of de Boor should also include Jos Stam's work: http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~stam/reality/Research/pub.html

(Especially his siggraph 1999 course notes, which cover a number of useful approaches for dealing with b-splines.)